# Why pitchEnabled is considered as a private API?

Tags: ios, ios7, appstore-approval, iphone-privateapi

Xcode failed to validate my app because

*This app references to non-public selectors in Payload/...*: **pitchEnabled**

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_7_0
if ([mapView respondsToSelector:@selector(pitchEnabled)]) {
    mapView.pitchEnabled = NO;
    mapView.rotateEnabled = NO;
}
#endif
```

Replacing `selector(pitchEnabled)` with `NSSelectorFromString(@"pitchEnabled")` solved this issue but makes me feel dirty, why `pitchEnabled` is considered as private API and what is the best approach to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are check for a method and not the property. And the getter method is `isPitchEnabled` not `pitchEnabled`.

```
// Rotate and pitch are enabled by default on Mac OS X and on iOS 7.0 and later.
@property (nonatomic, getter=isRotateEnabled) BOOL rotateEnabled NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 7_0);
@property (nonatomic, getter=isPitchEnabled) BOOL pitchEnabled NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 7_0);
```

Comment: This is the right idea, although Tuss is trying to use the setter, not the getter.

Comment: @Nate this should still work if you need to check whether the property exist. But yes you could also check if `setPicthEnabled:` exists.